# Possible to matplotlib's constrained_layout ignore axis tick labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a reasonably complicated grid of subplots that involves two sets (one on the left and another on the right) of columns plotting a set of quantities for each row, separated by a common legend to label the entries in each row.

[Here is a sample of what I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfU4N.jpg)

Using `matplotlib` with `constrained_layout = True` works 95% perfectly for applying the out optimal sizes & spacing for the columns, down to the tricky case of having the legend run down the middle. The remaining 5% is highlighted in red, where the wordy x-axis tick labels seem to push away the columns: it would be perfect if there was a way to make the layout engine "ignore" the tick labels in determining the spacing.

Methods using other libraries are also appreciated. Thank you in advance.

What I tried:

- `subplots_adjust`
- `GridSpec`

The main difficulty with those attempts:
`constrained_layout` is incompatible with those settings, so one must sacrifice the optimized legend spacing at the cost of getting the column spacing right, or vice versa.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not possible with the way constrained_layout is architected.  There was some idea that `set_in_layout` could take an x- or y- parameter, so in this case you could exclude the x-extent of each tick from the layout, but that seems really complicated, and not worth the bother.  If I had your situation, I'd just layout the positions by hand - it is not that hard.